# Why interface variables need initialization?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I want to create an interface that will force all classes that implement it to define a static final integer variable:

```
public interface FooInterface {
    static final int bar;
}
```

But the compiler says *"Variable 'bar' might not have been initialized"*. Why do I have to give it a value in the interface? I want every implementation to define its own value, so it seems illogical to me that I have to put there some arbitrary number that will never be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with an interface. All variables in an interface are implicitly `public final static`.

You could define `int getBar();` in the interface though, then all the implementing classes would need to return a value.

It would then be your responsibility to make sure that implementors are well behaved, but you can't prevent an implementation from returning different values, e.g.

```
public class Foo implements Bar {
    public int getBar() {
        return (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta sure you could write hostile code that returns random values, but that can't be solved with making the method static.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta A static method which you expect implementing classes to individually implement does not conceptually make sense.

Comment: @Michael Yes it does, it's just Java that does not support the concept of `abstract static`, which is easily supported in plenty of other languages.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Because it is supported in other languages doesn't mean it conceptually makes sense.

Comment: @Michael It means that Java has a strictly less-expressive object model than other languages.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why it's not allowed to declare the variable in the interface (not initialize), which would then force the *implementing classes* to initialize it (i.e., in their constructor)? This would seem logical to me.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký interfaces have always been about behaviour, not data. For me it would not be at all logical.

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking about this from the wrong angle.

A `static final` cannot be overriden in an implementing class.

You probably want to do it like this:

```
public interface FooInterface {
    int getBar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. An interface can only force the classes that implement it to implement methods.

A static variable defined in the interface belongs to the interface. It doesn't force implementing classes to declare the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

Every variables in an interface is static and final. final variables must be initialized on the first line or in the constructor. Because an interface doesn't have a constructor you must initialize final variable on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are final and final variables needs to be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal class, we have the option to define it like that and initialize its value in static initializer block:

```
public class FooClass {
    static final int bar;

    static {
        bar = 5;
    }
}
```

In case of an interface, static initialization block is not allowed that's why Java requires it to be set to a value at declaration.